# Youtube API v3 : access youtube videos using service account

Tags: .net, youtube-api, service-accounts, youtube-data-api

I am trying to use Google Service Account to list videos from YouTube Data API v3 in .NET. I have activated YouTube API, created Account Service, but whenever I am trying to list videos from my channel, it says 0 videos even if I do have uploaded videos. Could you please help ? Thanks.

Here is the code -

```
string[] scopes = new string[] 
{    
    YouTubeAnalyticsService.Scope.YtAnalyticsReadonly, 
    YouTubeAnalyticsService.Scope.YtAnalyticsMonetaryReadonly, 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl" 
};

// service account credential
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(SecretPath).CreateScoped(scopes);

var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = channelinfo.AnalyticsAPIFileDataStore
});

Dictionary<string, DateTime?> videoIds = new Dictionary<string, DateTime?>();

var channelResourcesList = youtubeService.Channels.List("contentDetails");
channelResourcesList.Id = channelinfo.ChannelId;
var listResult = channelResourcesList.Execute();
string playListId = listResult.Items[0]?.ContentDetails.RelatedPlaylists.Uploads;

var listOfVideos = youtubeService.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");

listOfVideos.PlaylistId = playListId;
var nextPageToken = "";

while (nextPageToken != null)
{
    listOfVideos.MaxResults = 50;
    listOfVideos.PageToken = nextPageToken;

    // searchresult is empty (listOfVideos.Execute() returns empty result) although channelResourcesList.Execute() worked
    var searchListResult = listOfVideos.Execute();
    nextPageToken = searchListResult.NextPageToken;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into the issue. I have updated the code.

Comment: AFAIK, [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/moving_to_oauth#standalone) doesn't support service account because it is not associated to any YouTube channel, and you cannot associate new or existing channels with service accounts.

Comment: In youtube API wiki - https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application it's mentioned "You can generate OAuth 2.0 credentials for web applications, service accounts, or installed applications."

Answer (score 3):

## update

In formation on how to configure a service account with use with the YouTube API can be found here. [Server sided web apps](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps)

As well as a C# example

```
GoogleCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                         .CreateScoped(scopes);
                }

                // Create the  YouTubeService service.
                return new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "YouTube Service account Authentication Sample",
                });
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is because it's outdated, but I am using Youtube Data API with Service Accounts as described in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You *can* configure a service account for use with Youtube API.  However, you will not be able to access any private content.  ["...you cannot associate new or existing channels with service accounts."](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/moving_to_oauth)